# GroupBy em Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, typescript

Estou recebendo o seguinte resultado de uma *query*:

```
[
  {
    "disciplina":"Portugues",
    "periodo":"1º Bimestre",
    "tipo":"1ª avaliacao",
    "valor":9.5
  },
  {
    "disciplina":"Matematica",
    "periodo":"1º Bimestre",
    "tipo":"1ª avaliacao",
    "valor":9.5
  }
]
```

Qual a melhor forma de deixar o resultado agrupado por período, depois por disciplina e em seguida por tipo?

Estou buscando esse resultado:

```
{
  "periodo":"1º Bimestre",
  "disciplinas":[
    {
      "nome":"Português",
      "tipo":[
        {
          "nome":"1ª avaliacao",
          "valor":9.5
        },
        {
          "nome":"2ª avaliacao",
          "valor":9.5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "nome":"Matemática",
      "tipo":[
        {
          "nome":"1ª avaliacao",
          "valor":8.5
        },
        {
          "nome":"2ª avaliacao",
          "valor":7.5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acabei desenvolvendo uma função mais genérica, apresentada abaixo.

```
function group_by (lista, coluna) {
  var colunas = {};
  var resultado = [];

  lista.forEach(function (item) {
    var reg = {};

    colunas[item[coluna]] = colunas[item[coluna]] || [];

    for (var i in item) 
      if (i != coluna) 
        reg[i] = item[i]; 

    colunas[item[coluna]].push(reg);
  });

  for (var i in colunas) 
    resultado.push({key: i, values: colunas[i]});

  return resultado;
}
```

Ela naturalmente faz o `group by` em apenas um nível, retornando uma lista de objetos com os atributos `key`, com o valor da coluna selecionada, e `values`, com os valores restantes.

Considere a entrada abaixo:

```
[
  {
    "disciplina": "Portugues",
    "periodo": "1º Bimestre",
    "tipo": "1ª avaliacao",
    "valor": 9.5
  },
  {
    "disciplina": "Matematica",
    "periodo": "1º Bimestre",
    "tipo": "1ª avaliacao",
    "valor": 9.5
  },
  {
    "disciplina": "Matematica",
    "periodo": "1º Bimestre",
    "tipo": "Trabalho",
    "valor": 9.5
  },
  {
    "disciplina": "Matematica",
    "periodo": "2º Bimestre",
    "tipo": "1ª avaliacao",
    "valor": 6.3
  }
]
```

Executando o `group_by` sobre a coluna `periodo`, `group_by(lista, "periodo")`, teríamos a seguinte saída:

```
[
  {
    "key":"1º Bimestre",
    "values":[
      {
        "disciplina":"Portugues",
        "tipo":"1ª avaliacao",
        "valor":9.5
      },
      {
        "disciplina":"Matematica",
        "tipo":"1ª avaliacao",
        "valor":9.5
      },
      {
        "disciplina":"Matematica",
        "tipo":"Trabalho",
        "valor":9.5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key":"2º Bimestre",
    "values":[
      {
        "disciplina":"Matematica",
        "tipo":"1ª avaliacao",
        "valor":6.3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Para obter um `group by` de segundo grau, por assim dizer, basta executar novamente a função sobre a lista presente em `values`, na coluna desejada. Por exemplo, para fazer agora o `group by` sobre a coluna `disciplina` e obter o resultado esperado, fazemos:

```
group_by(lista, "periodo").map(function (item) {
  return {key: item.key, values: group_by(item.values, "disciplina")};
});
```

Produzindo o seguinte resultado:

```
[
  {
    "key":"1º Bimestre",
    "values":[
      {
        "key":"Portugues",
        "values":[
          {
            "tipo":"1ª avaliacao",
            "valor":9.5
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "key":"Matematica",
        "values":[
          {
            "tipo":"1ª avaliacao",
            "valor":9.5
          },
          {
            "tipo":"Trabalho",
            "valor":9.5
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key":"2º Bimestre",
    "values":[
      {
        "key":"Matematica",
        "values":[
          {
            "tipo":"1ª avaliacao",
            "valor":6.3
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Que tal testar para uma entrada maior? Vamos supor ainda que queremos separar os registros de acordo com o `tipo`, para separar notas de provas, listas, etc.

```
group_by(lista, "periodo").map(function (item) {
  return {key: item.key, values: group_by(item.values, "disciplina").map(function(item){
    return {key: item.key, values: group_by(item.values, "tipo")}
  })};
})
```

A saída:

```
[
  {
    "key":"1º Bimestre",
    "values":[
      {
        "key":"Portugues",
        "values":[
          {
            "key":"Prova",
            "values":[
              {
                "valor":9.5
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key":"Lista",
            "values":[
              {
                "valor":8.8
              },
              {
                "valor":5.2
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "key":"Matematica",
        "values":[
          {
            "key":"Prova",
            "values":[
              {
                "valor":9.5
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key":"2º Bimestre",
    "values":[
      {
        "key":"Biologia",
        "values":[
          {
            "key":"Prova",
            "values":[
              {
                "valor":9.5
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "key":"Lista",
            "values":[
              {
                "valor":10
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key":"3º Bimestre",
    "values":[
      {
        "key":"Geografia",
        "values":[
          {
            "key":"Lista",
            "values":[
              {
                "valor":9.5
              },
              {
                "valor":9.9
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Esta solução serviu perfeitamente! Excelente! Muito obrigado Anderson. Abraço.

Comment: Talvez é possível ainda melhorá-la utilizando recursividade para chamar algo como `group_by(lista, ["periodo", "disciplina"])`, mas já estava tarde e não conseguia mais pensar.

Comment: Amigo, como converto o resultado desse seu código em uma tabela?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo basta fazer o `for` nos `values` e construir a tabela.

Answer (score 6):

Não sei se é a melhor forma, ou a mais eficiente, porém gera o resultado que precisa. Acredito que com os comentários no código é possível entender a lógica.

```js
var lista = [
  {
    "disciplina": "Portugues",
    "periodo": "1º Bimestre",
    "tipo": "1ª avaliacao",
    "valor": 9.5
  },
  {
    "disciplina": "Matematica",
    "periodo": "1º Bimestre",
    "tipo": "1ª avaliacao",
    "valor": 9.5
  },
  {
    "disciplina": "Matematica",
    "periodo": "2º Bimestre",
    "tipo": "1ª avaliacao",
    "valor": 6.3
  }
]

function group_by (lista) {
  
  var resultado = [];
  
  // Percorre todos os registros
  lista.forEach(function (item) {
    
    var idp = -1;
    var idd = -1;
    
    // Verifica se o periodo já está na lista final
    // Se sim, idp será o índice do respectivo objeto
    for (i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {
      if (item.periodo == resultado[i].periodo) {
        idp = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    
    // Se não, idp será -1, então cria o objeto na lista
    if (idp == -1) {
      idp = resultado.length;
      resultado.push({"periodo": item.periodo, "disciplinas": []});
    }
    
    // Verifica se a disciplina já está na lista do periodo
    // Se sim, idd será o índice do respectivo objeto
    for (i = 0; i < resultado[idp].disciplinas.length; i++) {
      if (item.disciplina == resultado[idp].disciplinas[i].nome) {
        idd = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    
    // Se não, idd será -1, então cria o objeto na lista
    if (idd == -1) {
      idd = resultado[idp].disciplinas.length;
      resultado[idp].disciplinas.push({"nome": item.disciplina, "tipo": []});
    }
    
    // Insere o tipo/valor na respectiva disciplina e periodo
    resultado[idp].disciplinas[idd].tipo.push({"nome": item.tipo, "valor": item.valor});
    
  });
  
  return resultado;
  
}

$(function () {
  $('pre').html( JSON.stringify(group_by(lista), null, 2) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>teste</pre>
```

> Pressione **Executar** para ver o código funcionando.

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo. Vou só adaptar pro typescript pois estou usando em um job com angular 2. Obrigado.