# Agrupamento de JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Olá,

Alguém pode me ajudar com este problema?

Tenho um retorno da API com vários registro no formato JSON, por exemplo:

```
[
    {data:“01/02/2010”, nome:“vivo”, janela:“00-02”, tipo:“ligado”},
    {data:“13/12/2003”, nome:“claro”, janela:“10-12”, tipo:“cancelado”},
    {data:“25/01/2017”, nome:“tim”, janela:“10-12”, tipo:“cancelado”},
    {data:“22/02/2010”, nome:“vivo”, janela:“00-02”, tipo:“ligado”},
    {data:“01/02/2010”, nome:“vivo”, janela:“08-10”, tipo:“cancelado”},
    {data:“03/04/2010”, nome:“tim”, janela:“10-12”, tipo:“cancelado”}
    {data:“22/02/2010”, nome:“claro”, janela:“08-10”, tipo:“cancelado”}
]
```

Eu preciso manipular esse JSON para esse formato, agrupado por data, depois por nome, por janela, por tipo e por fim fazer uma contagem de quantos tipos tenho,por exemplo:

```
let rows = [
    { data : “01/02/2010”, nome:“vivo”, intervals: [
        { name: “00-02”, types: [
            {name: “ligado”, qtd: 2}]
        }]
    }]
]
```

Caso não tenham entendido a pergunta tento explicar novamente.

Obrigado galera

Comment: Possível duplicata de [GroupBy em Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182050/groupby-em-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

você pode agrupar as informações que precisa fazendo um `filter`.

Ex:

```
const data = [
    {data:"01/02/2010", nome:"vivo", janela:"00-02", tipo:"ligado"},
    {data:"13/12/2003", nome:"claro", janela:"10-12", tipo:"cancelado"},
    {data:"25/01/2017", nome:"tim", janela:"10-12", tipo:"cancelado"},
    {data:"22/02/2010", nome:"vivo", janela:"00-02", tipo:"ligado"},
    {data:"01/02/2010", nome:"vivo", janela:"08-10", tipo:"cancelado"},
    {data:"03/04/2010", nome:"tim", janela:"10-12", tipo:"cancelado"},
    {data:"22/02/2010", nome:"claro", janela:"08-10", tipo:"cancelado"} ];
```

Para pegar os registros do dia '01/02/2010' você poderia fazer:

```
const dia01 = data.filter( item => item.data == '01/02/2010')
// Retorna: [{"data":"01/02/2010","nome":"vivo","janela":"00-02","tipo":"ligado"},{"data":"01/02/2010","nome":"vivo","janela":"08-10","tipo":"cancelado"}]
```

Para contar a quantidade de registros você pode usar o `length`

```
dia01.length
// Retorna: 2
```